Evolution of isotropic light in a closed empty room with fully reflective walls
I ponder the following hypothetical scenario:
There is a closed empty room, square in shape (if in 2D space, otherwise cubic if in 3D space), whose walls are fully reflective (in the true hypothetical sense, by some magic or otherwise). If a short burst of coherent white light is introduced into and then immediately removed from the room, what will the evolution of this light be?
EDIT2: Changed question wording from "If an isotropic light source is introduced for a unit period of time, which is not necessarily one second but rather just enough to produce a single wavefront of light, and then immediately removed from the room, ...?".
Will the photon-photon reactions lead to eventual dissipation of light within the system and its transformation to another state? ie what happens as time tends to infinity. Conversely, what is lost and what is gained after some finite number of reflections off such walls of the this light?
There is no observer in the room to see the light or obstruct its path in any way. Similarly, there are no particles inside the room to interact with photons in any way; I have neglected pressure for the thought experiment, but could relax the limitation if it plays, as I am sure it does, a role in its evolution.
I am not a physicist but an engineer, so suggestions as to further reading are welcome; however, kindly ask to assume no depth of knowledge of the workings of light on my part. In the meantime, I have stumbled upon so-called two-photon physics, which I assume to hold relevance to the case.
EDIT1: I have found similar questions asked online; however, the answers always seem to assume the walls to allow some degree of absorption, whereas my scenario allows none.
Thank you.

What photon-photon interactions? Without a non-linear medium (which you do not describe) there are no photon-photon interactions.

@JonCuster, could you elaborate what media are non-linear that allow photon-photon interactions?

The two-photon processes for which you provide links require atoms or molecules.  I presume your box contains a vacuum. And you tell us that the walls are ideal reflectors which implies no atomic or molecular structure.  So the two-photon processes seem to be irrelevent.  No?

I'm not sure what "one wave-front" of light means. Is this monochromatic? Or is it just a short burst of incoherent white light?
Not that it matters. If the room is a vacuum that light will bounce forever--though it will fall, accelerating at $g$.
If the room is full of air, then, estimating from:

let's say 10% absorption per atmosphere...after it passes through 100 atmospheres it will be:
$$ 100 \times (1-0.1)^{100} = 99.997%$$
absorbed.
One atmosphere is 100K pascal, divide by "g", to get
$$ \sigma = 10,000 {\rm kg/m^2}$$
The density is $\rho\approx 1$ kg per cubic meter, so that absorption will occur in after:
$$ L = \rho\sigma = 10,000\,{\rm m} $$
which takes:
$$ t = \frac L c = 33\,{\rm ms}$$
So it gets dark, quick.
Rayleigh scattering (The Tyndall Effect) does not occur at atmospheric pressure (the mean-free path is much shorter than a wavelength, $N_A$ is really big).
Note: photon-photon interactions have no relevance.

Yes, I did indeed mean a short burst of white light, coherent for simplicity.

Could you elaborate why photon-photon interactions have no relevance in the case that all we have are the photons?
